# Do not load the marker on google-maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know he is calling the function correctly, they put the marker does not appear on the map

```
<script>
    function newMarker(lat, long, id, marker){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
            });

            alert(id + ' ' + lat + ' ' + long);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, id) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent('sender');
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, id));
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#ads tbody tr").each(function(){
                tr=$(this);
                departureLatitude       = tr.children('td:eq(3)').html();
                departureLongitude      = tr.children('td:eq(4)').html();
                destinationLatitude     = tr.children('td:eq(5)').html();
                destinationLongitude    = tr.children('td:eq(6)').html();

                id = tr.children('td:eq(0)').html();

                var marker;
                newMarker(departureLatitude, departureLongitude, id, marker);
                markers.push(marker);
            });

            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
        });
</script>
```

however for that correctly loads the marker of the address entered in the field

```
<script>
function loadMap(campo, endereco, marker) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': endereco + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR'}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    campo.val(results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#bundle_ad_' + name_campo + 'Latitude').val(lat);
                    $('#bundle_ad_' + name_campo + 'Longitude').val(long);

                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Seu Destino!'
                        //draggable: true
                    });
                    marker.setPosition(location);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                    map.setZoom(15);
                }
            }
        });
    }

$("#bundle_ad_destination").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            loadMap($(this), $(this).val(), marker_destino);
        }
    });
</script>
```

I do the enstancia the map in this part of the code

```
<script>
function showGoogleMaps(){
    var mapConfig = {
        zoom: 15, // initialize zoom level - the max value is 21
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.132916, -34.82769),
        streetViewControl: false, // hide the yellow Street View pegman
        scaleControl: true, // allow users to zoom the Google Map
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), mapConfig);

    setStyleMap();

    getPosicion();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', showGoogleMaps);
</script>
```

the alert put up there to see if they would be carrying informations wrong or empty but alert appears all right, someone help me?

Comment: I haven't see anywhere instance of the map. You are using 
map: map, but in that code I can't see a line like:
google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('#map', {...params...}));

Probably because of this the marker is not placed in the proper map instance

Comment: I edited the question where do i estancia the map [link](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/jPjmyK.js)

Comment: Please construct the example in codepen or in jsfiddle in order to see where is the error, it's quite big code to debug it on the fly

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/jPjmyK) opencode
[link](https://gist.github.com/MarciusMcflay/15d6749732aedca5d6b0) github

Comment: Ok, when I load this code on codepen and allow the browser to know my location I can see the marker of my location, if I disable the location I see alert with an error message. So, what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: If you are watching will see that it has a function in js that peccore the fields of my table creating maker, maker those who are not showing up, and it is no question of them being outside the field of vision, because if you give a scrow it on the map no station anywhere

Comment: That this error appearing on the alert because here does not appear at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXoYzR)

1. There was a extra quote (") at the end of each cell containing the lng and lat so it was:

   -22.0040705"

instead of

```
-22.0040705
```

This lead to NaN in the google.maps.LatLng, which mean the markers wont show

2. You had a listener for window load (probably taken from the gmaps examples), but this event fires after the document ready (handled by jquery), so map in the newMarker() was undefined (next time try to debug with console.log(map). So to solve this I just called showGoogleMaps() in the document ready listener (line 491)
3. You were wrapping the each() function with a statement like

   $(function(){})

which was not right (line 509).

So, once I completed all these steps I've seen the markers on the map.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, lost a lot of time puzzling over this and not enchergava where was the error, it requires very same !!!